# JAXB check if XML-Tag has specific attribute

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I'm working at a Method to filter a collection (FileList) of xml-files if a specific xml-tag has an attribute...

In detail... I want to filter all xml-files where the xml-tag  has an attribute "is_special", but I've problems to setup my model-classes for the attribute.

At the end I want to store the name of the file and a list of its items, where the value has the attribute is_special="true"

Also I'm using the JAXB Framework with the Moxy extension...

The XML-Structure as followed:

```
<document>
<id>75C8866AB078DCE541256D16002CF636</id>
<size>806220</size>
<author>xxx</author>
<last_modified>2017.06.12 07:15:41 GMT</last_modified>
<added_to_file>2016.07.05 09:50:44 GMT</added_to_file>
<created>2003.04.28 08:11:06 GMT</created>
<items>
    <item>
        <name>someName/name>
        <type>LNITEMTYPE_DATETIMES</type>
        <values>
            <value is_special="true"/>
        </values>
        <last_modified>2003.04.28 08:11:10 GMT</last_modified>
        ...
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>someName/name>
        <type>LNITEMTYPE_TEXT</type>
        <values>
            <value>SOMETEXT</value>
            <value>SOMETEXT</value>
        </values>
        <last_modified>2003.04.28 08:11:10 GMT</last_modified>
        ...
    </item>
</items>
```

Therefor I've got 3 Classes for the XML-File...

"XMLDocument.java" implements the list of "Items.java" which implements the list of "Value.java"

XMLDocument.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "notes_document")
public class XMLDocument {

...
private List<Item> items;

...

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "items")
@XmlElement(name = "item")
public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
}
```

item.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "items")
public class Item {

    private String name;
    private List<String> values;
    private boolean valueIsSpecial;

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "values")
    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    @XmlPath("value/@is_special")
    public boolean getValueIsSpecial() {
        return valueIsSpecial;
    }

    public void setValueIsSpecial(boolean valueIsSpecial) {
        this.valueIsSpecial = valueIsSpecial;
    }
}
```

value.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "values")
public class Value {
    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    private String itemValue;
    @XmlPath("value/@is_special")
    private boolean isSpecial;

    public String getValue() {
        return itemValue;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.itemValue = value;
    }

    public boolean getValueIsSpecial() {
        return isSpecial;
    }

    public void setValueIsSpecial(boolean isSpecial) {
        this.isSpecial = isSpecial;
    }
}
```

My Method so far...

```
public void FilterTree_isSpecial() throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {

        for(String file: FileList) {
            if (file.endsWith(".xml") && !file.contains("databaseinfo.xml")) {

                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(NotesDocumentMetaFile.class);
                Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
                NotesDocumentMetaFile docMetaFile = (XMLDocument) um.unmarshal(new FileReader(file));
                for (int i = 0; i < docMetaFile.getItems().size(); i++) {

                    // CHECK IF THE <value> OF THIS ITEM HAS ATTRIBUTE is_special

                }               
            }
        }
    }
```

Much text... I hope anyone can give me a solution :/

Comment: There is an error in your XML. You should close the first "value" tag.

Comment: [edited] its closed by itself ... thanks for the hint

Comment: This could be easily done by java's xpath, do you need Jaxb for some ohter purpose ?

Comment: just using jaxb to unmarshal xml files and show the information. I think the problem lies in the @XmlPath annotation at "item.java" and "value.java" ... but I dont really get it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the xpath in your `Item.java` needs to be : `values/value/@is_special` like `@XmlPath("values/value/@is_special")`

If you want the `is_special` in your `Value.java` also your xpath should be :

`@is_special` like : `@XmlPath(@is_special)`

Also your `Item.java`, `Value.java` needs a little change. You don't need `@XmlRootElement`, you already had it in your `XmlDocument.java`

Your `Item.java` should be :

```
public class Item 
{

    private String name;

    private String type;

    private String lastModified;

    private List<Value> values;

    private String isSpecial;


    @XmlPath("values/value/@is_special")
    public String getIsSpecial() {
        return isSpecial;
    }

    public void setIsSpecial(String isSpecial) {
       this.isSpecial = isSpecial;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="type")
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="last_modified")
    public String getLastModified() {
        return lastModified;
    }

    public void setLastModified(String lastModified) {
        this.lastModified = lastModified;
    }


    @XmlElement(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @XmlElementWrapper(name="values")
    @XmlElement(name="value")
    public List<Value> getValues() {
        return values;
    }


    public void setValues(List<Value> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }


}
```

Your `Value.java` should be :

```
public class Value 
{

    @XmlPath("text()")
    private String value;

    @XmlPath("@is_special")
    private String isSpecial;

    public String getIsSpecial() {
        return isSpecial;
    }

    public void setIsSpecial(String isSpecial) {
        this.isSpecial = isSpecial;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


}
```

Note that to get `value` and `is_special` in `Value.java`, you could use `@XmlPath`.

Now you can call `getIsSpecial()` on `Item.java` to check if it is special.